How to fix this self-levelling gone wrong
Embarrassing, yes - but I have laid a self levelling compound and it has gone wrong. The pour went very well in terms of planning and timing, resulting in a very good looking result. I used a spiked roller, screeding spiders to gauge levels, and a wide trowel / float on a pole to push it around. But I was unable to get the compound to the correct places and was overly concerned about curing time, so I stopped working it too soon. Result is a floor that's out of whack (average 6mm but up to 10-12mm in very small areas).
I plan to fix it myself but have questions.
Preliminary - This was a fibre-reinforced self levelling compound over a plywood subfloor (on joists supported by steels), the subfloor was prepared carefully and screwed down adequately. There was not much movement in the subfloor. I used two layers of primer as a moisture barrier then gritted primer, according to advice from data sheet and manufacturer of SLC (self levelling compound). The compound was mixed in three very large (75L) buckets and poured without delay, but thoroughly.
Data sheet suggests it can be laid up to a maximum of 6mm over timber floor. Given the minimum thickness of the compound (3mm) I take this to mean that it can only actually level a subfloor by about 3mm. This was the product recommended by manufacturer when I spoke to them. My plywood subfloor was out of whack by average 6mm (some places more) but I decided this would be within tolerance and risk of delamination of plywood underneath was low, so I took the risk and indeed there's no evidence of de-lamination so that's good.
The problem: I had mis-measured the floor heights and mis-calculated the required amount of compound (used 13 bags in total for a 20 sq m floor that was average 4-6mm out). Turns on this compound was quite thick, despite using the correct amount of water in the mix it definitely did need assistance in levelling, more than I gave it.
Now the floor is out by approximately the same amount e.g. 4-6mm around most of the area, but also up to 10-14mm in smaller areas (in one corner for example).
Furthermore I made the following mistakes:

I was too concerned about working very quickly, so I didn't work the levels enough with trowel
I did not have spiked shoes, and I was concerned about walking in the compound as it would ruin the finish, which is why I didn't work it enough
I used the screed tripods incorrectly, setting them up so the TOP of each plate would be level with the compound instead of the bottom. In the end I removed them far sooner than I should have, again out of concern I needed to get out of the flooring area so it could set without interruption.
I should have mixed and poured each bucket one after the other, instead of mixing 3 very large buckets at the same time then pouring at the same time. Although this seems like a good idea, it does mean that you can't work the levels systematically. I had assumed that I just need to use spiked roller a bit and it would all self-level fine.

Options:
I have grinded down the high spots now, so I could do one of two things:

As per data sheet do NOT pour more screed as 6mm is the maximum over plywood. The reason for this is to avoid delamination of the plywood caused by tensile strength of product. Instead use shims EVERYWHERE and bond them down, then overlay e.g. 12mm plywood. I previously had a sheet of 12mm ply hanging around and tested this with shims, it resulted in a very solid floor, however I subsequently purchased 8 sheets of "flooring grade plywood" in 12mm to get this job done, but the new plywood I have seems far less dense (my test plywood was actually quite heavy for a sheet of 12mm but this stuff is light) and it does flex between shims. I even tested adding some PU foam between shims in a small area, but I'm not happy with the amount of flex still.

Despite the risk of subfloor plywood de-laminating, most people I've spoken to suggest it will be fine and I should re-lay more compound on top. This goes against the data sheet and I would be concerned about this. One manufacturer suggested it will be fine as long as I use a compound with a LOWER compressive strength than the previous one. However I've checked and the data sheet of the compound I used (Wakol Z520) does not list the compressive strength. For reasons I won't cover here I'm unable to call their technical team to enquire about this.


So - what's my best course of action right now? I would like a floor within reasonable tolerance to be able to lay reclaimed parquet floor on top.
plywood subbase prior to priming / levelling:

photo of newly laid compound:

photo showing cured compound with grading numbers across the floor denoting how far below level each point is:


What kind of finish and use for the room do you have in mind? If that is a living room with a sofa and a table, I would just leave it as as even with +/-10mm over large area.

Problem is that the variation of 12mm is not averaged across the area. There are lumps (not obvious to the eye, but you can see them with even a short spirit level in some places) - craters of say 6mm across a 1200mm level. So laying parquet floor will be nearly impossible. I have bought 12mm ply to overlay, but in order to get everything flat, many boards would need only shims holding them up, if that makes sense. I'd rather shim and ply, but the ply is just too thin and I've spent a lot of money on that ply now!

In the US, there is DAP Webpatch 90, or Henry Feather finish. Either one will allow low spots to be filled in and feathered out to a fine edge.
If neither of these products are available across the pond, there should certainly be a compatible product that can accomplish what you need.
The self levelers have a very high compressive strength, the one I use is about 5,000 psi as I recall. These other products are quite soft by comparison, IMO.

Thanks, that’s a very helpful answer.  A UK manufacturer Ardex told me about a feather finish product which I could try. Are these products you mentioned dry mixes that you trowel on? Do you think that’s a reasonable course of action for such a large area? I’d be prepared to do it with a dry mix that can be applied with trowel (rather than pouring a liquid) even if it’s a lot of work, as I know I can get it flat and level that way.

Ardex is out this way too. A very good product. Yes I refer to a troweled product. My course of action would be, using a large enough straight edge to span the depressions, and preferably a permanent marker to mark the outline where the depressions begin. Then using the same straightedge, using that to "strike"/ level the mix over the depression, firstly, using a trowel to get it close. It WILL be rough, but no higher than the rest of the floor. After that set up, then give the roughness a tight skim to fill in the surface flat.
